# Move decimal fixed number of spaces with Ruby

Tags: ruby, numbers

I have large integers (typically 15-30 digits) stored as a string that represent a certain amount of a given currenty (such as ETH). Also stored with that is the number of digits to move the decimal.

```
{
    "base_price"=>"5000000000000000000",
    "decimals"=>18
}
```

The output that I'm ultimately looking for is `5.00` (which is what you'd get if took the decimal from `5000000000000000000` and moved it to the left 18 positions).

How would I do that in Ruby?

Comment: Do you want to perform the operation on strings?  Or are you looking to get a numerical value (like a floating point value) out of the operation?

Comment: `val = h['base_price'].to_i / 10.0 ** h['decimals'] #=> 5.0` or you could use `val = h['base_price'].dup.insert(h['base_price'].length - h["decimals"],'.') #=> "5.000000000000000000"` convert to a numeric using your favorite flavor of conversion e.g. `val.to_f`, `BigDecimal(val)`, `Float(val)`, etc.

Comment: @ScottThompson Final format is mostly irrelevant. It's a display thing for the end user. Just want to represent `5000000000000000000` as `5.00` on the output.

Comment: What if the integer is `5006` and `"decimals"` equals `3`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given:

```
my_map = {
    "base_price"=>"5000000000000000000",
    "decimals"=>18
}
```

You could use:

```
my_number = my_map["base_price"].to_i / (10**my_map["decimals"]).to_f
puts(my_number)
```

Comment: Shpigford, this produces the float `5.0`, whereas you said the desired result is `5.00`, which presumably is a string.

Answer (score 1):

```
h = { "base_price"=>"5000000000000000000", "decimals"=>18 }
```

​

```
bef, aft = h["base_price"].split(/(?=\d{#{h["decimals"]}}\z)/)
  #=> ["5", "000000000000000000"]

bef + '.' + aft[0,2]
  #=> "5.00"
```

The regular expression uses the positive lookahead `(?=\d{18}\z)` to split the string at a ("zero-width") location between digits such that `18` digits follow to the end of the string.

Alternatively, one could write:

```
str = h["base_price"][0, h["base_price"].size-h["decimals"]+2]
  #=> h["base_price"][0, 3]
  #=> "500"
str.insert(str.size-2, '.')
  #=> "5.00"
```

Neither of these address potential boundary cases such as

```
{ "base_price"=>"500", "decimals"=>1 }
```

or

```
{ "base_price"=>"500", "decimals"=>4 }
```

Nor do they consider rounding issues.

Answer (score 0):

Regular expressions and interpolation?

```
my_map = {
    "base_price"=>"5000000000000000000",
    "decimals"=>18
}

my_map["base_price"].sub(
    /(0{#{my_map["decimals"]}})\s*$/, 
    ".#{$1}"
)
```

The number of decimal places is interpolated into the regular expression as the count of zeroes to look for from the end of the string (plus zero or more whitespace characters).  This is matched, and the match is subbed with a `.` in front of it.

Producing:

```
=> "5.000000000000000000"
```